# How can I add throws IOExcpetion to this code?

Tags: file, ioexception, filewriter, printwriter, throws

This is my main class:

```
public class Table extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable
{
    public void init()
    {
        Balla.addBall();
    }
}
```

This is the Balla method:

```
public static void addBall()throws IOException
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Ball b = new Ball(100,100,8,Color.blue,generator.nextInt(4)+1,generator.nextInt(4)+1);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\temp_Jon\\BallData.ballz",true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw,true);
        pw.print(b.getX()+" "+b.getY()+" "+b.getRadius()+" "+b.color+" "+b.speedX+" "+b.speedY);
        fw.close();
        pw.close();
    }
```

Now my question come from when I complie it. It tells me that I have an unreported IOException in the init method, but when I add the throws IOException on the method it tells me:
 **error: init() in Table cannot override init() in Applet**

How can I get around this and/or how can I fix this without modifying to much of everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
public static void addBall()throws IOException
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Ball b = new Ball(100,100,8,Color.blue,generator.nextInt(4)+1,generator.nextInt(4)+1);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\temp_Jon\\BallData.ballz",true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw,true);
        pw.print(b.getX()+" "+b.getY()+" "+b.getRadius()+" "+b.color+" "+b.speedX+" "+b.speedY);
        fw.close();
        pw.close();
    }
```

to

```
public static void addBall()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Ball b = new Ball(100,100,8,Color.blue,generator.nextInt(4)+1,generator.nextInt(4)+1);
        try
{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\temp_Jon\\BallData.ballz",true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw,true);
        pw.print(b.getX()+" "+b.getY()+" "+b.getRadius()+" "+b.color+" "+b.speedX+" "+b.speedY);
        fw.close();
        pw.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
}
}
```

and see if it works

Comment: I mean it got rid of the error but it doesn't actually ever seem to write to the file.

Comment: add this line in catch block and see the error : e.printStackTrace();

Comment: that's elementary then, change the path to other drive e.g. D: , and you should be through. Also please accept the answer